# PHPMailer Error: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in LOCALHOST(XAMPP)

Tags: php, email, xampp, smtp, phpmailer

First of all, I am using XAMPP on Mac OS and the latest PHP mailer and I know that this might be related to DNS issue, but please read.

This is the full error:

`2021-06-06 09:04:03 Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:587, timeout=300, options=array()`

`2021-06-06 09:04:23 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution [/opt/lampp/htdocs/enfu2020/123abc/srcs/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php line 388]`

`2021-06-06 09:04:23 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to smtp.gmail.com:587 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution) [/opt/lampp/htdocs/enfu2020/123abc/srcs/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php line 388]`

`2021-06-06 09:04:23 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution (0)`

`SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting`
`Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting`

**And heres' the code:**

```
try {

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

//Server settings
$mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'anymail@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'anyPassword';                                //SMTP password
   $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;


//Recipients
$mail->setFrom('anymail@gmail.com', 'My Cool Name');
$mail->AddAddress($email_1, $namatim);     // Add a recipient
$mail->AddAddress($email_2, $namatim);     // Add a recipient
$mail->AddAddress($email_3, $namatim);     // Add a recipient
$mail->addReplyTo('anymail@gmail.com', 'My Cool Name');

//Content
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Verification Success';
$mail->Body    = 'This is a message';

$mail->send();
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

From the troubleshooting [page](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#dns-failures), I can see that this is indicated as a DNS issue. I suspect this is a problem of my XAMPP's DNS.

I've tried to do `dig +short smtp.gmail.com` on my local machine and it works fine BUT when I clicked on Open Terminal button on XAMPP, and tried to run the same command, that command does not work.

I am wondering what config needs to be changed on my php.ini, or anything really (I've added extensions=openssl, but still the same error I got).

I'd really appreciate it if there's anyone out there that has the way to fix this and willing to share it to me as I'm totally clueless right now and been stuck with it for hours.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you have a DNS problem. PHPMailer is not the right tool to try to fix or diagnose it though. Get dig working inside XAMPP, and PHPMailer will be able to work. I’d start with the XAMPP docs.

Answer (score 0):

```php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
```

You have to Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace,
and These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function.

For use:

```php
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

You have to use this command inside your parent directory, because your PHPMailer class will be executed from "Vendor" folder.

```
composer dump-autoload
```

You can check my code:

https://github.com/mhreza76/php_pondit/blob/main/session_06/public/php-mailer.php

Comment: Hey, yes I actually have added all the "use" and "require" on the top of the file, and also instantiated the $mail = new PHPMailer(true); still no luck. Any clue?

Comment: This answer is true, but doesn’t answer the question that was asked